# swagger widdershins slate html markup issue

Tags: markdown, swagger, slate

I need to compile swagger files into html files. I do:

Create json file on editor.swagger.io.
Generate markdown by the command:

```
widdershins endpoint.json -o ./endpoint.html.md
```

Then generate html by command:

```
middleman build
```

Then I copy files to apache, but final html markup is quite different than I expected. Sometimes parameter sections are absent, or POST parameters are not shown. Are there any compatibility issue? I use

https://github.com/lord/slate
https://github.com/Mermade/widdershins

Answer (score 0):

Author of Widdershins here. Please raise an issue on github with a link to your swagger/openapi definition, and we'll try and debug it.